# Regex to match a slug?

Tags: php, regex

I'm having trouble creating a Regex to match URL slugs (basically, alphanumeric "words" separated by *single* dashes)

```
this-is-an-example
```

I've come up with this Regex: `/[a-z0-9\-]+$/` and while it restricts the string to only alphanumerical characters and dashes, it still produces some false positives like these:

```
-example
example-
this-----is---an--example
-
```

I'm quite bad with regular expressions, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: @zzzzBov I'm using PHP (with the preg_match function).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use this:

```
/^
  [a-z0-9]+   # One or more repetition of given characters
  (?:         # A non-capture group.
    -           # A hyphen
    [a-z0-9]+   # One or more repetition of given characters
  )*          # Zero or more repetition of previous group
 $/
```

This will match:

1. A sequence of alphanumeric characters at the beginning.
2. Then it will match a hyphen, then a sequence of alphanumeric characters, 0 or more times.

Comment: Great! This works _almost_ as I want. Can you tweak it in order to match a single word too? (I forgot to mention that single words are considered valid slugs too).

Comment: @fedeetz: Just replace last `+` with `*` (0 or more matches)

Comment: Great, thank you very much. I'll accept this as soon as I can.

Comment: One question, on this kind of regex (validate a slug), what's the purpose of the **non-**capture group? Why not a capture group? I am asking because with JS I use RegExp.prototype.test() so I don't care about the groups.

Comment: @mathieug First, capturing group isn't wanted by the author, so what's the point of having it in your results? Secondly, The group is repeated, so with a repeated capturing group, only the last repetition would captured.

Comment: for the lazy: `/^[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*$/`

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! This work great. Can you do one that accepts hyphens and underscores? I tried editing this, but couldn't!

Comment: will not match non-ascii characters which are allowed in a slug.

Comment: @Yandiro `/^[a-z0-9]+(?:[_-][a-z0-9]+)*$/`

Answer (score 0):

A more comprehensive regex that will match both ascii and non-ascii characters in slugs would be,

```
/^             # start of string
 [^\s!?\/.*#|] # exclude spaces/tabs/line feed.. as well as reserved characters !?/.*#
 +             # match one or more times
$/             # end of string
```

for good measure we exclude the [reserved URL characters](https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html).

so for example, the above will [match](https://regex101.com/r/RWs0Zn/1)

```
une-ecole_123-soleil
une-école_123-soleil
une-%C3%A9cole-123_soleil
```