# Regular Expression for A-Z, Dash using Data Annotations

Tags: c#, regex, data-annotations

I need a regular expression for a URL-friendly slug, which can **only contain lowercase letters and hyphens**. It can't start or end with a hyphen and can't have more than one consecutive dash.

It will be used in a data annotation in C#:

```
[RegularExpression("", ErrorMessage = "Slug can only contain lowercase letters and dash; must not start or end with a dash; must not have more then 1 consecutive dash.")]
```

I tried the following expressions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256323/regex-to-match-a-slug).

```
/^[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*$/
/^[a-z0-9]+(?:[_-][a-z0-9]+)*$/
```

1. How can I modify the expressions to validate what I need?
2. Can someone further explain how the non-capture group works in this case? I didn't understand the explanation I got from Google.

> c-sharp (valid)
> c-sharp-code (valid)
> -csharp (invalid)
> csharp- (invalid)
> c--sharp (invalid)
> csharp9 (invalid)
> c_sharp (invalid)

Comment: The non-capturing groups are because you need _a group_ to attach a quantifier (`+`) too, but without the cost of it being a normal capturing group.

Comment: ...but for your needs, you don't need any noncapturing-groups (or any groups at all).

Comment: Protip: use Regex101.com for help with regular-expressions.

Comment: I think you mean like this without matching digits right? `^[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*$` https://regex101.com/r/a05kLh/1

Comment: @Dai I can't get it to work without that non-capturing group. If I remove it, it no longer seems to check for consecutive hyphens.

Comment: You have correct regexps, no need to make them more complicated with any lookaheads.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Use:

```
^[a-z](?!.*--)[a-z\-]*[a-z]$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/qXNO3y/3

#### Explanation:

```
^             # Anchor at start of string.
[a-z]         # The first character must be in the range [a-z].
(?!.*--)      # Assert that "--" does not appear anywhere from this point onwards.
[a-z\-]*      # Allow any subsequent chars to be in the range [a-z], or be '-' (while never matching "--" due to the assertion prior).
[a-z]         # The last character must be in the range [a-z]
$             # Anchor to the end of the string.
```

#### Usage:

```
static readonly Regex _slugRegex = new Regex( @"^[a-z](?!.*--)[a-z\-]*[a-z]$", RegexOptions.Compiled );

_slugRegex.IsMatch( "foo-bar"  ); // OK

_slugRegex.IsMatch( "foo--bar" ); // Fails
_slugRegex.IsMatch( "foo-bar-" ); // Fails
_slugRegex.IsMatch( "-foo-bar" ); // Fails
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, because it allows digits.

Comment: @KennethR.Jones Whoops, sorry. check now.

Comment: Almost, but it still validates "csh-a-rp-". That should fail, because there is a dash at the end.

Comment: Third-time lucky?

Comment: @KennethR.Jones What what says?

Answer (score 0):

This expression also answers the question:

```
^[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*$
```

It meets all the requirements I originally needed.